# Perl regex replacement when replacement is numeric

Tags: regex, perl

This is probably something really silly, and I apologize if that is the case. I don't know exactly what to search for, and I haven't had any luck with the searches I've ran over the past half hour or so. Anyway...

So I want to automate making a simple change to xml with perl as part of a build process. This is the change I'm making, it's part of a config file called `mapred-site.xml`

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb</name>
-    <value>1024</value>
+    <value>4096</value>
</property>
```

I've got a perl regex replacement that does exactly what I need it to do, until I change this `FOO` to `4096`

```
cat mapred-site.xml | perl -p0e "s/(yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb<\/name>\s*?<value>)....(<\/value>)/\\1FOO\\2/s"
```

Guessing that the problem is that there are numbers directly next to the `\\1` referring to the first portion, and it's pulling them in and trying to do `\\14096` or similar, but I haven't been able to come up with a solution.

I apologize if the command itself is sloppy/inefficient, I'm still just getting started with these commands.

Comment: I don't see numbers on either side of the `\\1` capture group in your replacement.  That being said, doing regex replacements on HTML content usually is not such a good idea.  Use a parser instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `\1`, `\2` etc. on the right side of a regex is about a million years old anyway; the recommended way is to use `$1`, `$2`, etc. And if you use those you can use braces to separate the variable name from any neighboring stuff, like `${1}FOO${2}` (or, just as well, `${1}4096${2}`).

Comment: `cat mapred-site.xml | perl -p0e "s/(yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb<\/name>\s*?<value>)....(<\/value>)/\${1}4096\${2}/s"` worked wonderfully, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a less fragile/more maintainable way to do it, using [Mojo::DOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM):

```
cat mapred-site.xml | perl -CSD -0777 -MMojo::DOM -pe '$_ = Mojo::DOM->new->xml(1)->parse($_); $_->find("property > name")->first(sub { $_->text eq "yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb" })->following("value")->first->content(4096)'
```

As a more readable script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Mojo::DOM;
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';

my $dom = do { local $/; Mojo::DOM->new->xml(1)->parse(readline \*STDIN) };

my $name = $dom->find('property > name')
  ->first(sub { $_->text eq 'yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb' });
$name->following('value')->first->content(4096);

print $dom->to_string;
```